# Epson L210 printer

Tags: printer

Few weeks ago I bought this printer but only yesterday I unboxed it and start testing it. The problem comes when I want to print something. Firstly, it printed out a blank page. So I thought of giving it a try couple of times just to make sure the ink reached the printer head. After 3 hours trying finally some ink came out. The only color that came out is magenta and yellow. The blue and blank ink is yet to be seen. What can I do to solve this problem? I already tried for head cleaning. Only God knows how many time I did it. Please help.

Comment: It shouldn't do that.  Since it's new, I would contact the seller for an exchange.

Answer (score 0):

As fixer1234 said, contact the seller and exchange it.

If you want to test the ink, get a piece of tissue, scrunch it up, stick it next to the nozzles and shake hard...

If you don't see anything, it is possible the cartridge is dried up.

If you do see some colour, it is actually worse as most likely the printer heads are jammed.

In the first case - easy to solve/get a new cartridge. In the second case, it can be a big support issue that isn't always worth the price to fix, so, if you have a warranty - use that.